# Rearranging complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $$u(y, t) = \Re{\left\{UF(y)e^{int}\right\}}$$ where $F$ is a complex function, $n$ is an integer and $i=\sqrt{-1}$. If $u(a, t) = -u(-a, t) = U\cos{(nt)}$, show that $F(a) = -F(-a) = 1$. So we have

$u(a, t) = \Re{\left\{UF(a)e^{int}\right\}} = U\cos{(nt)}\Re{\left\{F(a)\right\}} = U\cos{(nt)} \implies \Re{\left\{F(a)\right\}}  = 1.$

$u(-a, t) = \Re{\left\{UF(-a)e^{int}\right\}} = U\cos{(nt)}\Re{\left\{F(-a)\right\}} = U\cos{(nt)} \implies \Re{\left\{F(-a)\right\}}  = 1.$

So how do you make the last step to conclude? We can't remove the $\Re$ since $F$ is a complex function.

Comment: $F$ is a complex function so it has a real and imaginary part. Therefore $\Re\{F(a)\} = 1 \not\implies $F(a) = 1$ as it gives no information about the imaginary part.

Comment: Exactly.. so $\Re\{1+2i\} = 1$ does not imply $1+2i=1$...

Comment: I understand that but surely that's irrelevant. I want to show $F(a) = 1$ and I have $\Re\{F(a)\} = 1$ so we know that $F(a) = 1+bi$ where $b$ is real. Now how do I conclude that $b=0$?

Comment: Is It $F(x)$or $F(y)$ ?

Comment: Ah my mistake, it is $F(y)$ and we should have $u(y, t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let suppose:
$$F(a)= A(a) + jB(a)$$

$$u(a,t)=URe[A(a)cos(nt)+jA(a)sin(nt)+jB(a)cos(nt)-B(a)sin(nt)]=U(A(a)cos(nt)-B(a)sin(nt))=Ucos(nt)$$
$$u(-a,t)=URe[A(-a)cos(nt)+jA(-a)sin(nt)+jB(-a)cos(nt)-B(-a)sin(nt)]=U(A(-a)cos(nt)+B(-a)bsin(nt))=-Ucos(nt)$$

therefore,

$$B(a)=B(-a)=0$$
$$A(a)=-A(-a)=1$$

Comment: I have noticed a mistake here. We must show $F(-a) = -1$ but you have shown $F(-a) = 1$. Also there are a few typos in the answer.

Comment: @MichaelHowlard I fixed it, I am very busy right now, If there is other mistake tell me, I will correct them. thanks BTW